# PHP can't update data across ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to update data in mysql with ajax PHP, but the data doesn't get updated and I also get a json error message that says 'Unexpected end of JSON input', but don't understand why. Each modal form has different ID like this:

```
<form id="userData<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" method="post">
    <div class="modal fade" id="userModal-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="userModalLabel-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="userModalLabel-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['username']; ?> felhasználó</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label for="premiumSelect">Prémium</label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="premiumSelect-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="premiumSelect">
                        <option value="">Premium</option>
                        <option value="1">Bronze</option>
                        <option value="2">Silver</option>
                        <option value="3">Gold</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="adminSelect">Admin</label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="adminSelect-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="adminSelect">
                        <option value="">Admin</option>
                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                        <option value="0">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" name="user-submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm trying to access to the form id in jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //form when submit
    $("form[id*=userData]").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "user-settings.php",
            method: "post",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(message) {
                var response = JSON.parse(message);
                alertify.success(response.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the user-settings.php file:

```
session_start();
require_once("../config.php");

if (isset($_POST['user-submit'])) {

    $userid = $_POST['userID'];
    $premium = $_POST['premiumSelect'];
    $admin = $_POST['adminSelect'];
    $premiumstart = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $premiumexpiration = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+30 days', strtotime($premiumstart)));

    $stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE users SET premium=?, premiumstart=?, premiumexpiration=?, admin=? WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('issii', $premium, $premiumstart, $premiumexpiration, $admin, $userid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $link->close();

    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'premiumexpiration' => $premiumexpiration,
            'message' => 'Success!'
        )
    );
}
```

I checked the network tab in chrome, and all the data in there:

```
FormData:
premiumSelect: 3
adminSelect: 1
userID: 19
```

but in the response tab, it says 'This request has no response data available'.

Comment: Your FormData doesn't seem to include the `user-submit` field. Your update doesn't run unless that is set. Or did you just leave it out of this post for some reason? You could add an `else()` clause and output a JSON-encoded error message if that field is not set, or check for submission using `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {` instead.

Comment: what have you done to troubleshoot this so far? Does the request get sent OK with ALL expected data ( use the console to monitor )? Are there errors in the PHP ( check the log ) Is `error_reporting` enabled in PHP?

Comment: 'Your FormData doesn't seem to include the user-submit field.' I don't really understand this part. I'm submitting the form with ```<button type="submit" name="user-submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>``` Could you explain it where and what should I type? @droopsnoot

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I checked the network tab, and all expected data in there

Comment: _“I'm submitting the form with [button]”_ - no, you are not. You explicitly suppressed the default action of this button (submitting the form), with `e.preventDefault();` You are sending the data via AJAX _instead_. And in that data, you did not include any parameter named `user-submit`.

Comment: @droopsnoot Seems like you are right. I put an else() clause and my code goes there. But where should I add the 'user-submit' field?

Comment: Don’t add it at all, check for one of the parameters that _are_ getting sent instead.

Comment: Sorry for being so dumb, but I don't understand how to check that. @CBroe

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['userID']))`

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, it works now. If you have some time, could you show me how I should do this with user-submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the demo below there is dummy data used to populate a single modal as per the question. The Ajax function is essentially the same except that the url is set to the same page for testing, dataType set to json and the `alertify` commented out.

The ajax function does happily send the form contents but the logic used to process the form submission failed due to testing which fields were present in the POST array. You should always test for the important fields rather than whether a button has been clicked. The following ignores completely the `user-submit` in the PHP processing and the utility `preview_mysqli` should be useful(?) diagnosing what will be executed by php.

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    
    
    // dummy data
    $row=array(
        'id'        =>  23,
        'username'  =>  'geronimo'
    );
    
    // utility to emulate what a mysqli prepared statement would execute..
    function preview_mysqli( $sql, $args ){
        $index=0;
        for( $i=0; $i < strlen( $sql ); $i++ ){
            $char = substr( $sql, $i, 1 );
            if( $char == '?' ) {
                $param = $args[ $index ];
                if( !strstr( $param, '"' ) )$param=sprintf( '"%s"', $param );
                $sql = substr_replace( $sql, $param, $i, 1 );
                $index++;
            }
        }
        return preg_replace( '@(\t)@', ' ', $sql );
    }
    
    
    
    /*
        The important pieces of information are these here
        so use the `isset` function to determine if these are
        available before proceeding rather than a submit button
        which is not used.
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['userID'],
        $_POST['premiumSelect'],
        $_POST['adminSelect']
    )){
        
        
        $userid = $_POST['userID'];
        $premium = $_POST['premiumSelect'];
        $admin = $_POST['adminSelect'];
        $premiumstart = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $premiumexpiration = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+30 days', strtotime($premiumstart)));

        $sql='UPDATE users SET premium=?, premiumstart=?, premiumexpiration=?, admin=? WHERE id=?';
        $args=array( $premium, $premiumstart, $premiumexpiration, $admin, $userid );
        
        
        // comment this line out after testing
        // this will show roughly what is to be executed... does it look correct?
        exit( preview_mysqli( $sql, $args ) );
        
        
        
        
        if( isset( $link ) ){
            
            $stmt = $link->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param('issii', ...$args );
            $status=$stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            $link->close();
            
            exit( json_encode(
                array(
                    'premiumexpiration' => $premiumexpiration,
                    'message'           => $status ? 'Success!' : 'Bogus!'
                )
            ));
        }
        
        
        
        exit(false);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("form[ id*='userData' ]").submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: location.href, //"user-settings.php"
                        method:"post",
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        dataType:"json",
                        success: function( json ) {
                            //alertify.success(response.message);
                            console.info( json )
                        }
                    });
                });
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="userData<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" method="post">
            <div class="modal fade" id="userModal-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="userModalLabel-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="userModalLabel-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['username']; ?> felhasználó</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <label for="premiumSelect">Prémium</label>
                            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="premiumSelect-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="premiumSelect">
                                <option value="">Premium</option>
                                <option value="1">Bronze</option>
                                <option value="2">Silver</option>
                                <option value="3">Gold</option>
                            </select>
                            <label for="adminSelect">Admin</label>
                            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="adminSelect-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="adminSelect">
                                <option value="">Admin</option>
                                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                <option value="0">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I got it now! :)